# get objectId from relation parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, relationship

i use parse to save an load my core data's records.
i have 2 classes: Activite and Famille. Famille have only 1 relation with Activite.

when i make a query to get all Famille's data how i can get the relation (the objectId) from Activite ?

```
    func loadDataFromParse(){

    let query = PFQuery(className:"Famille")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {

        (famille: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        let familleA = NSMutableArray()

        if error == nil {

            print("Successfully retrieved \(famille!.count) familles.")

              print(famille)

                for object in famille! {

                    let familleDico = NSMutableDictionary()

                    familleDico.setObject((object.valueForKey("nom")!), forKey: "nom")

                    familleDico.setObject((object.valueForKey("objectId")!), forKey: "id")

                    familleDico.setObject((object.valueForKey("createdAt")!), forKey: "dateCreation")

                    familleDico.setObject((object.valueForKey("updatedAt")!), forKey: "dateModif")

                    familleDico.setObject((object.valueForKey("tauxRem")!), forKey: "tauxRem")

                    familleDico.setObject((object.valueForKey("remuneration")!), forKey: "remuneration")

                    familleDico.setObject((object.valueForKey("tva")!), forKey: "tva")

                    familleA.addObject(familleDico)

                     print(famille)

                }


               // self.verifDateAvantMaj(familleA)
                // self.insertDataToCoreData(activiteA)
           // }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

when i use `print(famille)` i have this:
 `Optional([<Famille: 0x7f95abc3cfe0, objectId: ciEf9sdT4B, localId: (null)> {
    inActivite = "<PFRelation: 0x7f95abc3d1a0, 0x0.(null) -> Activite>";
    nom = Tableterie;
    remuneration = Marge;
    tauxRem = 5;
    tva = 20;
}`

So it's possible to get the PFRelation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the PFRelation object, you can get that by doing

```
let relation = object.relationForKey("inActivite")
```

Answer (score 0):

The relation is analogous to a join table in sql.  You can get the value of the relation like this:

```
let relation = object.relationForKey("inactivate")
```

Relations provide a query that can be run to get the related objects:

```
let inactiveQuery = relation.query()
inactiveQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (inactives: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // inactives is an array of the related objects
```